# Image in Primefaces feedReader

Tags: jsf, primefaces

When the Primefaces feedReader is used in a JSF page, it gets the image of the feed automatically.
On my page there are three columns. The first one has the FeedReader, and, when the feed has an image, it exceeds the column size and invades the second column.

I've already tried the property escape="false", but it doesn't leave the text exceeds the column, not the image. Is there any way to correct this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to remove the images manually. I looked through the API, and I didn't see anything that will do it automatically.

You can pass the data to a backing bean to remove the image with whatever parsing method you want.

```
<p:feedReader value="http://rss.news.yahoo.com/rss/sports" var="feed">
    <h:outputText value="#{feed.title}" style="font-weight: bold"/>
    <h:outputText value="#{backingBean.removeImages(feed.description.value)}" escape="false"/>
</p:feedReader>
```